# Adding a Proxmox 5.x node to 4.3 cluster

Tags: cloud, proxmox

I am performing an upgrade on my cloud cluster. 
I have 5 nodes which are running currently on 
**Proxmox Virtual Environment 4.3-12/6894c9d9**
I need to upgrade them to newest 5.x version. The upgrade tutorial provided on the wiki is easy to understand but it strikes a few questions which I can not find/get answers to. 
If I upgrade 1 out of my 5 nodes to 5.x will I be able to add the node into existing cluster or will I need to upgrade all node to 4.4?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Proxmox documantations](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_4.x_Cluster):
 **NOTE: It is not possible to mix Proxmox VE 3.x and earlier with Proxmox VE 4.0 cluster** 

But **you can have Proxmox VE +4.x in one cluster** and there will be no problem.